# Packages kept back after do-release-upgrade

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, 22.04, do-release-upgrade

Not sure if this is a bug.

I try to run unattended release upgrade freshly installed jammy to lunar using:

`do-release-upgrade --frontend=DistUpgradeViewNonInteractive  --allow-third-party  --mode=server --proposed`.

After rebooting, the OS still greets me with a friendly `Welcome to Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS`.

All the repos are lunar, the kernel is 6.2.0-39. Looks like a lunar to me. Running `apt upgrade` I see that three packages are held back.

`The following packages have been kept back: base-files motd-news-config tzdata`

I can see from `apt policy` that these are subject to phased updates. Maybe it's just me, but ... I think I need this packages now.

What to do?

Comment: You can install them with `aptitude`, it ignores the phasing nonsense.

Comment: The upgrade path from 22.04 (Jammy) to 23.04 (Lunar) is possible, but untested and unsupported. There might be lots of similar undiscovered papercuts (term meaning "minor bug") because it's untested. Those papercuts are unlikely to be fixed because that path is unsupported. Advice is the same for all folks who have left the marked path: Have fun, do regular backups, and know how to return to supported territory.

Comment: >  but untested and unsupported.

Then maybe `do-release-upgrade` shouldn't do it? 